# PostgreSQL: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-12

I have a `main.comments` table where I store users comments.
I'm trying to add a comment to the database and get some data as a return.
Here's my query

```
INSERT INTO main.comments (text, post_id, user_id)
VALUES('sample', 11, 1)
RETURNING 
comment_id,
text,
post_id,
(SELECT username FROM main.users WHERE main.users.user_id = user_id) AS username,
created_at,
updated_at
```

So I was expecting to add a comment and get the data I wanted but that wasn't the case, instead I got this error

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

I thought I had a problem with the subquery so I used it individually and got only one row in return.
So I used `LIMIT 1` within the subquery and I got the result I was expecting but that doesn't make sense in my query. Can someone please explain this behavior?
And also my `main.users` table doesn't contain any `user_id` duplicate since I'm using the `SERIAL` type.

- PostgreSQL 12.4

Comment: The `WHERE` condition in the subquery will be `TRUE` for all rows where `user_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for you response, is there any solutions to that or should i just stick with workarounds like LIMIT?

Comment: @aingthed Limit Workaround will not work. it will give wrong name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Culprit is this line in your code

```
(SELECT username FROM main.users WHERE main.users.user_id = user_id)
```

Try it like This:

```
INSERT INTO comments (text, post_id, user_id)
VALUES('sample', 11, 1)
RETURNING 
comment_id,
text,
post_id,
(SELECT username FROM users t1 WHERE t1.user_id = comments.user_id) AS username,
created_at,
updated_at
```

[DEMO:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e9675e01b2addc281bbc5eecf3bbcd39)

```
I have removed the schema name for clarity
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `user_id` in your subquery is *not* referring to the newly inserted row in `main.comments`, but to `main.users`, so the condition becomes `TRUE` and all rows from `users` are returned.

I'd use a CTE it like this:

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO main.comments (text, post_id, user_id)
   VALUES('sample', 11, 1)
   RETURNING 
      comment_id,
      text,
      post_id,
      user_id,
      created_at,
      updated_at
)
SELECT ins.comment_id,
       ins.text,
       ins.post_id,
       u.username,
       ins.created_at,
       ins.updated_at
FROM ins
   JOIN main.users AS u ON ins.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could first enter blank values

```
       INSERT INTO main.comments (text, post_id, user_id)
    VALUES('sample', 11, 1)
    RETURNING 
    comment_id,
    text,
    post_id,
    NULL AS username,
    created_at,
updated_at;
```

then update your table

```
UPDATE main.comment 
SET username = (SELECT username )
FROM main.users 
WHERE main.users.user_id = main.comment.user_id;
```

didn't test but should work